# Consolidating substring values into a cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet where I am tracking list of books as below.

| Book name |
| --- |
| Blue Lock, Vol. 1 |
| Naruto, Vol. 9 |
| Harry Potter (novel), Vol. 2 |
| Naruto, Vol 10 |
| Girl, unframed |

I have a query where I am able to consolidate all duplicates and remove suffixes.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(((QUERY({QUERY(Sheet1!A:M, "select A, C, J where A is not null"), REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(Sheet1!A:M, "select A where A is not null"), "(.*),")}, "select Col4, Count(Col4), Col2 where Col4 is not null and Col3 = 'Y' group by Col4, Col2 label Col4 'Book Name', Count(Col4) 'Volumes'"))))`

I am only able to get the count of each occurrence of a string using the `Count(Col4)` function. How do I make it so that each entry will have the list of volumes in a separate column like below?

| Book name | Volumes |
| --- | --- |
| Blue Lock | 1 |
| Naruto | 9, 10 |
| Harry Potter (novel) | 2 |
| Girl, unframed |  |

[Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L2o1bmWAoMlXHDJiLJesATynMj3TURu_-Pq4oft1o7c/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: To help you get a more accurate answer, it would be beneficial if you could provide a minimal, reproducible example, such as a dummy sheet, that demonstrates the issue you're facing along with your desired result. This would allow the community to better understand your problem and provide targeted solutions. Including a reproducible example will greatly increase your chances of receiving a helpful response.

Comment: @Saddles Thank you for the idea. I have updated my post with an example.

Comment: Does the formula need to look just into Column A (*Book name + Volume number*) **OR** only filter books with Received Status(*Column J*)  ="Y"

Comment: @rockinfreakshow It needs to pick up only the values that have 'Y' in column J.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ,ifna(filter({regexextract(A2:A,"(.*?)(?:,|$)"),regexextract(A2:A,"(\d+)$")},J2:J="Y")),
    map(unique(index(Σ,,1)),lambda(Γ,{Γ,textjoin(", ",1,ifna(filter(index(Σ,,2),index(Σ,,1)=Γ)))})))
```

[image]

**`FORMULA_BREAKUP`**

***step 1 (separating book name and volume number)***

```js
=ifna(filter({regexextract(A2:A,"(.*?)(?:,|$)"),regexextract(A2:A,"(\d+)$")},A2:A<>""))
```

***step 2 (picking unique book names)***

```js
=let(Σ,ifna(filter({regexextract(A2:A,"(.*?)(?:,|$)"),regexextract(A2:A,"(\d+)$")},A2:A<>"")),unique(index(Σ,,1)))
```

***step 3 (filtering volume numbers for each unique book and joining them)***

```js
=textjoin(", ",1,filter(S:S,R:R=T2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If possible, could you please explain each part of the query? I would like to understand how it works.

Comment: Added possible explanation part to the answer

Comment: Thank you for adding the explanation. Marking your answer as correct.

Comment: There is one issue I have with the regex. Where there are multiple commas in a book title, only the first comma is captured instead of the last one in this regex `"(.*?)(?:,|$)"`. Previously I had used this regex, `(.*),`, to pick only the last comma in string.

Comment: Is there a way to pick the whole string if there is no last comma? I have updated the dummy excel to demonstrate the scenario.

Comment: Can you highlight those multiple comma scenario(s) in your test sheet and also enter the expected output (manually) in separate columns so that I can have a clear picture of what is expected

Comment: I have edited my question and also highlighted the cell where the comma scenario is needed.

Comment: Updated the formula in your test sheet